# Removing last 'after' in wp_nave_menu in array

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have separators set between the navigation, however, I don't want it to show after the last menu item.

Do I need to write some javascript to fix this?

You can see what I'm talking about here: gofish2o.davelaphamblog.com

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( 
    array(
        'theme_location'=>'header-menu',
        'after' => '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/seperator.png"/>'
    )); 
?>
```

Comment: You can try http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp last-child selector in CSS3.

Comment: Ok cool!  I'm trying to stick away from CSS3.  Any other ways possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't stick away from CSS3, you should embrace it. We need to move the web forward, not hang back with Internet Explorer.

At any rate, here's a couple of ways to solve this.

```
jQuery('#menu-main li:last-child img').remove();
jQuery('#menu-main li:last-child img').css({display : 'none'});
```

That will remove it using jQuery

```
#menu-main li:last-child img{
     display:none;
}
```

That will remove it using CSS

I personally would just create a border-right on the list elements as opposed to using an image.

Comment: Great point!  They are actually different heights of what the border would be and they have a slight fade to them.

Comment: Ahh I see, didn't look closely at the lines.  This link will show you browser support for last-child.  You shouldn't have any worries using the last-child psuedo selector for CSS.

[last-child browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child)

Answer (score 0):

I just knocked this up for you.

```
ul#main_nav li:last-child > img {display:none}
```

Seemed to work ok? Let me know. Just add it to your style sheet